# Easy hard cider recipe

Tags: cider

I'm looking for an easy hard cider recipe that doesn't take long to make and hopefully ends up like angry orchard or at least tasty. Recipe should take me from start to finish. I already tried to make one using a recipe I found myself and it ended up nasty tasting. I would prefer to use things I already have which are:

- 1 Gallon Indian Summer Apple Cider
- A lot of brown sugar
- Fleischmanns active dry yeast
- Fleischmanns rapid rise yeast
- raisins
- cinnamon

Also please don't post recipes you haven't tried and verified yourself to be delicious. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**F'emUpus Hard Cider 11% ABV**

ABV pushes this into Apple wine territory.

***Into fermentor:***

4 Gallons Martinelli's Apple juice

4 lb organic cane sugar

OG 1.085

1 pack rehydrated/proofed Dry Champaign Yeast, yeast nutrients, 1 liter o2

72° F

FG 0.990 12% ABV
It's was very dry and alcoholic at this point.

***Back sweetening:***
Reduced concentrated 5000ml Martinelli's Apple Juice and 5 cinnamon sticks to 2000ml. 
This addition made for a sweet hard cider ABV 11% after dilution.

Took 2nd place in two different competitions, 35-38 points BJCP C2E Spiced Cider. Only flaw flagged by judges was "too sweet".  To do again I would reduce the Back sweetening by 30%

I kegged and refrigerated to prevent secondary fermentation, so other process would be needed for bottle conditioning and warm storage.

Comment: So nothing I can really do with my ingredients I listed?

Comment: Would it end up tasting ok if I did same with my ingredients?

Comment: @TalC IDk, but you do have makings for a cider, use only 1lb of sugar for 1 gal. Don't use raisins.

Comment: Why no raisins? Someone recommended it before? I did add some other stuff in the mix (cinnamon and cranberries)in the plastic bottle fermenter and bottled it in sterilized a and w bottles. I didn't boil anything. Ended up tasting very odd and I think plasticy :/

Comment: Although I wouldn't attribute the plasticky taste to the a and w because I tried a little taste before bottling and it was weird then too.

Comment: @TalC raisins are a perfect medium for wild yeast. Added care needs to be taken to use them by blanching. Also ever get that one funky raisin in a box? It's enough to make strange flavors in a small batch.